# How can I solve this mysterious error: torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: pytorch, gpu

Until today my GPU had no error, but suddenly torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError error occured.
Message went like this:

> torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 534.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 23.65 GiB of which 360.56 MiB is free. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 23.29 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 20.73 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 2.10 GiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

Tried solutions mentioned in similar questions.
`import torch torch.cuda.empty_cache()`

`import gc gc.collect()`

`export PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=max_split_size_mb:128`

But nothing worked for me.

My batch size is 4, and GPU has 23GB of memory.